# HTML5 Video — limiting buffer for an MP4

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Is it possible to use an HTML5 Video tag to load an MP4, but control how much of the file is downloaded/buffered from the server (assume it supports byte ranges).

Essentially, I'd like to be able to say "only download 60 seconds ahead" so I can avoid the browser downloading an entire 2 GB file when the user is going to end up bouncing anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading chunks into html5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789417/loading-chunks-into-html5-video)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: browsers will automatically buffer only what they need, rather than download the whole file. It is not necessary to try and control the buffering from a "custom" HTML5 player POV.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65501042/2982234

You could use the media-fragment syntax in the url to let the browser know which portion of the media it should play.

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = ({target}) => {
  target.remove();
  document.querySelector("video").play();
};
```

```css
video { max-height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<button>play</button>
<video muted src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm#t=0,60"></video>
```

Comment: You would need to constantly alter the source while the video is playing to achieve what capped buffering during play does. Unless it actually handles this very smoothly, I imagine it would feel like the video is constantly being reloaded.